# Connecting neighbouring pixels(nucleus segmentation)

Tags: image, image-segmentation

I am using image processing techniques  in  order  to  detect the  white  blood  cells  and  classification  of  leukocytes through image segmentation. I did morphological opening to remove small pixel groups.Now i want to connect the neighboring pixels to count and locate the nuclei of the WBC . How can i do that?

input image:
[image]

after morphological operation:
[image]

Comment: you question is a bit unclear: can yo add an example input image, and the map you get after your morphological operation and a better description of what you are hoping to get from these inputs?

Comment: Which are the white blood cells? Which are the leukocytes? What are all the objects present on the input image? What are all the things present on the output image? Where are the nucleii you want to count? How many are there? Please provide annotated images AND also images without annotation. Thank you.